Script Condition Support
This is a bit outside of my area of expertise, but I am running a script that calls out to update certain information via the APIs available as part of a service we subscribe to.  It works mostly great with one exception.  In the part where it parses data, if it doesn't see that data it fails.  How can I aadjust this script (the bit at line 20) to handle a lack of data more gracefully?
The error Google spits out when it reached a container number where it doesn't get an ETA (again... could be for any reason including a typo in the container or that the container has already delivered).  It's the "Extract ETA" section.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pod')
updateETAs    @ code.gs:20

THANKS!
function updateETAs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var containerNumbers = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues(); // Get all container numbers from column A
  var apiKey = "REMOVED"; // Replace with your API key

  // Loop through each container number
  for (var i = 0; i < containerNumbers.length; i++) {
    var containerNumber = containerNumbers[i][0];

    // Skip empty cells
    if (containerNumber === "") continue;

    // Make API request
    var apiUrl = "REMOVED" + containerNumber + "&api_key=" + apiKey;
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
    var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    // Extract ETA
    var eta = responseData.data.route.pod.date;

    // Update ETA in column B
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(eta); // Save ETA in column B
  }
}


Hoping that if the script reaches a container it cannot get an ETA for, it will just move on to the next one.

Try something like this:
function updateETAs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cns = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var apiKey = "REMOVED";
  cns.forEach((cn, i) => {
    try {
      if (cn) {
        var apiUrl = "REMOVED" + cn + "&api_key=" + apiKey;
        var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
        if (r) {
          var responseData = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
          if (responseData.data.route.pod.date) {
            var eta = responseData.data.route.pod.date;
            sh.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(eta);
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Container Number is null`)
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      Logger.log(`Failed with Error: ${e}\n at row ${i+1}`);
      continue;
    }
  });
}

